# method invocation may produce nullpointerexception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement Graph using adjacency list, but when I try to add new pair into the list it gaves me an `NullPointerException`. Is there anyone know why it would happen and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

My `Graph.java` is like:

```
import javafx.util.Pair;
import java.util.*;

public class Graph{
    private final HashMap<String, List<Pair<String, Integer>>> adj;

    public Graph(String filePath) {
        adj = new HashMap<>();
        addEdge("a", "b", 30);
    }

    public void addEdge(String start, String end, int weight) {
        adj.get(start).add(new Pair<>(end, weight));
    }
}
```

My `Main.java` is like:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Graph gr;

        try {
            gr = new Graph("test.txt");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fingal - you have not included the stacktrace in your question.  Since finding the cause of an NPE without a stacktrace is largely guesswork, your Question was marked as a duplicate of a generic Q&A with answers that explain how to debug and fix NPEs for yourself.  Your subsequent revision of the question did not help.

Comment: However here's a hint.  What will `adj.get(start)` return when `adj` is a newly created (and hence empty) `HashMap`?

Answer (score -1):

Just putting `new Graph()` in your second constructor doesn't initialize it. You just declare a default graph and don't store it anywhere. Now if you use the special function `this`, you'll get what you want.

```
public Graph(String filePath) {
    this();
    ...
```

Comment: You're right, but this is not what cause this problem. I tried to use `this()` but it didn't work.

Comment: You're *not* right. In OP's code, there is no zero-arg constructor. As such, adding `this();` wouldn't compile.